# How to correctly print read lines in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am having a weird behavior when trying to iterate over a plain text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n "5,5p" test.tmp
while read linea in
do 
    echo $linea
done < test.tmp
```

The thing is that from the first sed I get what I expected, but from the while loop I don't:

```
./test.sh 
 (5) Sorgo                                              DICOTILEDONEAS                               1,5-2 l/ha          15
(1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
(5)
(6)
```

I am attaching both files in order to help clarifying what is happening here:

- Script: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3sx8zbglvyti7w/test.sh?dl=0
- Input data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5jq8dl162jpofv/test.tmp?dl=0

Thanks in advance

Comment: IFS split lines on whitespace. Redefine it so only newline divide input

Comment: `echo $linea`, first off, adds a great many bugs compared to `echo "$linea"`, or -- much better -- `printf '%s\n' "$linea"`.

Comment: Beyond that, see BashFAQ #1 for a comprehensive discussion of reading input correctly: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Also, your `sed` command reads the file and writes output to stdin -- but your `while` loop iterates over the original file, not the output from `sed`.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your responses. It is clear I must study scripting in depth, but I only need scripting once in years and I forget everything.

Just to clarify my post. The sed command is just an example of command that is working as I expected to show a specific line, I do not want it as an input for the loop. 

I will check tomorrow if this works... Scripting syntax is still a mystery for me after years of using it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was going on. There was an extra "in" within the while statement. Probably I mixed two different kind of whiles.

Where I had:

while read linea in
do 
    echo $linea
done < test.tmp

It should read:

while read linea; **## in removed and ; added**
do 
    echo $linea
done < test.tmp

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

What I would do :

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r linea; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$linea"
done < <(sed -n "5,5p" test.tmp)
```

`< <( )` is a process substitution, check
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst

---

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Need to clear `IFS` and use the `-r` argument to `read` to be completely accurate. As it is, this strips trailing whitespace (or other `IFS` characters) and processes backslash-escape sequences into their associated characters.

Comment: Also, `printf '%s\n' "$linea"` would have fewer corner cases than `echo`; consider behavior with a line containing only `-n`.

Comment: You should probably mention what the `--` does as well even if it's not required in this case.

Comment: `echo -- "$linea"`, to be compliant with POSIX, would print the literal characters `--`; same as in `printf`; this is why I was advising against its use in either of these cases.